# Use another UITableView in a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController,with its own tableview.
But I still want to have another UITableView whose Data Source And Delegate are in another Class.

the symptom is: **iPhone 4.0 can't show the UITableView , while The iPhone 6.0 Simulator can show this UITableView in a visiable and right way.**

NSLog told me UITableView's height is 0.0 when on iPhone.

The Problem is : I will get the second UITableView by

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;`

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

doesn't have any response...

Comment: How have you added the datasource and delegate of second tableview?

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper I added them. -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  this method is performed .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Create two objects for UITableView.

> numberOfRowsInSection part do this

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView
  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  if(tableView == tblLog)
    return 3; //Or whatever value
   else
    return 2;
  }

> CELLFORROWATINDEX part do this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UILabel *headingLabel;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
    }

    if(tableView == tblLog)
    {
        switch (indexPath.row)
        { 
            case 0:
            {
                //do something

            } break;

            case 1:
            {
               //do something

            } break;
        }

    }
    else if (tableView == tblRange)
    {
        switch (indexPath.row)
        { 
            case 0:
            {
                //do something
            }break;

            case 1:
            {
                //do something
            }break;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: It's a second choice for me to do switching tableview, Because I had the UITableView's DataSource and Delegate in another class.  Temperarily, I don't want to put them all in a file. Looking forward to your advice.